# Performance issues when creating custom components. Need TIPS

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am in the process of converting an excel desktop application into flex. Obviously excel has far better grid functionality but it also looks better so I am trying to recreate it manually versus using the spark advanceddatagrid/datagrid. To do this I am creating a ton of groups and  representing each cell as a bordercontainer with a label embedded in it. It looks great but it takes a while to draw as I am drawing each component as I iterate through my arraycollection.

The code looks similar to this

```
for each(var factor:Factor in this._model.assessment.factors)
            {
                //draw factor header
                var factorHeaderBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                factorHeaderBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x2d4a6c");
                factorHeaderBackground.width = 1370;
                factorHeaderBackground.height = 30;

                var factorNameLabel:Label = new Label();
                factorNameLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                factorNameLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                factorNameLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                factorNameLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                factorNameLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "18");
                factorNameLabel.setStyle("color", "white");
                factorNameLabel.text = factor.name;
                factorNameLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                factorHeaderBackground.addElement(factorNameLabel)
                this.chart.addElement(factorHeaderBackground);
                for each (var metric:Metric in factor.children)
                {
                    var headerGroup:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    headerGroup.gap = 0;
                    /** 
                     * this adds the first section of the header (far left)
                     * */
                    var criteriaColumn:VGroup = new VGroup();
                    criteriaColumn.gap = 0;

                    var topCriteriaHeader:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    topCriteriaHeader.gap = 0;
                    var bottomCriteriaHeader:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    bottomCriteriaHeader.gap = 0;

                    //draw top section of criteria header
                    var metricNumberBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    metricNumberBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    metricNumberBackground.width = 70;
                    metricNumberBackground.height = 30;

                    var metricNumberLabel:Label = new Label();
                    metricNumberLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    metricNumberLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    metricNumberLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    metricNumberLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    metricNumberLabel.text = 'Metric ' + metric.measureNumber;
                    metricNumberLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                    metricNumberBackground.addElement(metricNumberLabel);

                    var metricNameBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    metricNameBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    metricNameBackground.width = 300;
                    metricNameBackground.height = 30;

                    var metricNameLabel:Label = new Label();
                    metricNameLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    metricNameLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    metricNameLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    metricNameLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    metricNameLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "16");
                    metricNameLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    metricNameLabel.text = metric.name;
                    metricNameLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                    metricNameBackground.addElement(metricNameLabel);
                    topCriteriaHeader.addElement(metricNumberBackground);
                    topCriteriaHeader.addElement(metricNameBackground);

                    criteriaColumn.addElement(topCriteriaHeader);

                    //draw bottom section of criteria header
                    var blankBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    blankBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    blankBackground.width = 70;
                    blankBackground.height = 30;

                    var criteriaNameBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    criteriaNameBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    criteriaNameBackground.width = 300;
                    criteriaNameBackground.height = 30;

                    var criteriaNameLabel:Label = new Label();
                    criteriaNameLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    criteriaNameLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    criteriaNameLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    criteriaNameLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    criteriaNameLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "14");
                    criteriaNameLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    criteriaNameLabel.text = "Criteria";
                    criteriaNameLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                    criteriaNameBackground.addElement(criteriaNameLabel);
                    bottomCriteriaHeader.addElement(blankBackground);
                    bottomCriteriaHeader.addElement(criteriaNameBackground);

                    criteriaColumn.addElement(bottomCriteriaHeader);

                    /** 
                     * this adds the second section of the header
                     * */
                    var currentColumn:VGroup = new VGroup();
                    currentColumn.gap = 0;

                    var bottomCurrentHeader:HGroup = new HGroup();
                    bottomCurrentHeader.gap = 0;

                    //draw top section of current header
                    var currentBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    currentBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    currentBackground.width = 300;
                    currentBackground.height = 30;

                    var currentLabel:Label = new Label();
                    currentLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    currentLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    currentLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    currentLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    currentLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "18");
                    currentLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    currentLabel.text = 'Current';
                    currentLabel.verticalCenter = 1;
                    currentBackground.addElement(currentLabel);

                    currentColumn.addElement(currentBackground);

                    //draw bottom section of current header
                    var ratingBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    ratingBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    ratingBackground.width = 60;
                    ratingBackground.height = 30;

                    var ratingLabel:Label = new Label();
                    ratingLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    ratingLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    ratingLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    ratingLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    ratingLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "10");
                    ratingLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    ratingLabel.text = "Rating";
                    ratingLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                    ratingBackground.addElement(ratingLabel);
                    bottomCurrentHeader.addElement(ratingBackground);

                    var manualUpDownBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    manualUpDownBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    manualUpDownBackground.width = 60;
                    manualUpDownBackground.height = 30;

                    var manualUpDownLabel:Label = new Label();
                    manualUpDownLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    manualUpDownLabel.height = 30;
                    manualUpDownLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "top");
                    manualUpDownLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    manualUpDownLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    manualUpDownLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "10");
                    manualUpDownLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    manualUpDownLabel.text = "Manual" + "\nUp/Down";
                    manualUpDownLabel.verticalCenter = -6;

                    manualUpDownBackground.addElement(manualUpDownLabel);
                    bottomCurrentHeader.addElement(manualUpDownBackground);

                    var standardWeightingBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    standardWeightingBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    standardWeightingBackground.width = 60;
                    standardWeightingBackground.height = 30;

                    var standardWeightingLabel:Label = new Label();
                    standardWeightingLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    standardWeightingLabel.height = 30
                    standardWeightingLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "top");
                    standardWeightingLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    standardWeightingLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    standardWeightingLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "10");
                    standardWeightingLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    standardWeightingLabel.text = "Standard" + "\nWeighting";
                    standardWeightingLabel.verticalCenter = -6;

                    standardWeightingBackground.addElement(standardWeightingLabel);
                    bottomCurrentHeader.addElement(standardWeightingBackground);

                    var customWeightingBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    customWeightingBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    customWeightingBackground.width = 60;
                    customWeightingBackground.height = 30;

                    var customWeightingLabel:Label = new Label();
                    customWeightingLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    customWeightingLabel.height = 30;
                    customWeightingLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "top");
                    customWeightingLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    customWeightingLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    customWeightingLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "10");
                    customWeightingLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    customWeightingLabel.text = "Custom" + "\nWeighting";
                    customWeightingLabel.verticalCenter = -6;

                    customWeightingBackground.addElement(customWeightingLabel);
                    bottomCurrentHeader.addElement(customWeightingBackground);

                    var scoreBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                    scoreBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x6699CC");
                    scoreBackground.width = 60;
                    scoreBackground.height = 30;

                    var scoreLabel:Label = new Label();
                    scoreLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                    scoreLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                    scoreLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                    scoreLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                    scoreLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "10");
                    scoreLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                    scoreLabel.text = "Score";
                    scoreLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                    scoreBackground.addElement(scoreLabel);
                    bottomCurrentHeader.addElement(scoreBackground);

                    currentColumn.addElement(bottomCurrentHeader);

                    headerGroup.addElement(criteriaColumn);
                    headerGroup.addElement(currentColumn);
                    headerGroup.addElement(rationaleColumn);
                    headerGroup.addElement(futureColumn);
                    headerGroup.addElement(futureRationaleColumn);

                    this.chart.addElement(headerGroup);

                    var criteriaLength:int = metric.children.length;
                    var criterionCounter:int = 0;

                    for each (var criterion:Criterion in metric.children)
                    {
                        criterionCounter += 1;

                        var criteriaGroup:HGroup = new HGroup();
                        criteriaGroup.gap = 0;

                        //adds name column
                        var criterionNumberBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                        criterionNumberBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", criterion.isCritical ? "0xFF9933" : "0xFFFFFF");
                        criterionNumberBackground.width = 70;
                        criterionNumberBackground.height = 60;

                        var criterionNumberLabel:Label = new Label();
                        criterionNumberLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                        criterionNumberLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                        criterionNumberLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                        criterionNumberLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                        criterionNumberLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "12");
                        criterionNumberLabel.text = criterion.measureNumber;
                        criterionNumberLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                        criterionNumberBackground.addElement(criterionNumberLabel);
                        criteriaGroup.addElement(criterionNumberBackground);

                        //adds criteria description column      
                        var criterionDescriptionBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                        criterionDescriptionBackground.width = 300;
                        criterionDescriptionBackground.height = 60;

                        var criterionDescriptionLabel:Label = new Label();
                        criterionDescriptionLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                        criterionDescriptionLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "left");
                        criterionDescriptionLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                        criterionDescriptionLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                        criterionDescriptionLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "12");
                        criterionDescriptionLabel.text = criterion.description;
                        criterionDescriptionLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                        criterionDescriptionBackground.addElement(criterionDescriptionLabel);
                        criteriaGroup.addElement(criterionDescriptionBackground);

                        //add current standard rating column
                        var criterionCurrentStandardRatingBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", criterion.score.currentStandardRatingType.color().toString());
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingBackground.width = 60;
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingBackground.height = 60;

                        var criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel:Label = new Label();
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "12");
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel.text = criterion.score.currentStandardRatingType.toString();
                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                        criterionCurrentStandardRatingBackground.addElement(criterionCurrentStandardRatingLabel);
                        criteriaGroup.addElement(criterionCurrentStandardRatingBackground);

                        //add current manual/upgrade combobox column                
                        var criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
                        criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox.width = 60;
                        criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox.height = 60;
                        criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox.dataProvider = rateTypeComboBoxItems;
                        BindingUtils.bindProperty(criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox, "selectedItem", criterion.score, "currentUpgradeDowngradeRatingType");
                        BindingUtils.bindProperty(criterion.score, "currentUpgradeDowngradeRatingTypeFromComboBox", criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox, "selectedItem");
                        criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox.verticalCenter = 1;
                        criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox.labelField = "Text";

                        criteriaGroup.addElement(criterionCurrentManualUpgradeDowngradeComboBox);                            

                        var totalGroup:HGroup = new HGroup();
                        totalGroup.gap = 0;

                        //draw last row for each criterion
                        if(criterionCounter == criteriaLength)
                        {
                            //stores weights for current / future
                            var totalCurrentStandardWeight:Number = metric.AggregateWeights(true, true);
                            var totalCurrentCustomWeight:Number = metric.AggregateWeights(true, false);
                            var totalFutureStandardWeight:Number = metric.AggregateWeights(false, true);
                            var totalFutureCustomWeight:Number = metric.AggregateWeights(false, false);
                            //adds total column
                            var criterionTotalBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                            criterionTotalBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0xa6a6a6");
                            criterionTotalBackground.width = 370;
                            criterionTotalBackground.height = 15;

                            var criterionTotalLabel:Label = new Label();
                            criterionTotalLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                            criterionTotalLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                            criterionTotalLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                            criterionTotalLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                            criterionTotalLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "12");
                            criterionTotalLabel.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");
                            criterionTotalLabel.text = metric.name + "Criteria Total";
                            criterionTotalLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                            criterionTotalBackground.addElement(criterionTotalLabel);
                            totalGroup.addElement(criterionTotalBackground);

                            //add rating dummy column
                            var criterionRatingFillerBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                            criterionRatingFillerBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0xa6a6a6");
                            criterionRatingFillerBackground.width = 60;
                            criterionRatingFillerBackground.height = 15;

                            totalGroup.addElement(criterionRatingFillerBackground);

                            //add manual up/down dummy column
                            var criterionUpDownFillerBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                            criterionUpDownFillerBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0xa6a6a6");
                            criterionUpDownFillerBackground.width = 60;
                            criterionUpDownFillerBackground.height = 15;

                            totalGroup.addElement(criterionUpDownFillerBackground);

                            //add current standard weight column
                            var criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalBackground:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalBackground.setStyle("backgroundColor", totalCurrentStandardWeight < 100 ? "0xf4f120" : "0xa6a6a6");
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalBackground.width = 60;
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalBackground.height = 15;

                            var criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel:Label = new Label();
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel.percentWidth = 100;
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel.setStyle("verticalAlign", "middle");
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel.setStyle("horizontalAlign", "middle");
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel.setStyle("textAlign", "center");
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel.setStyle("fontSize", "12");
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel.text = totalCurrentStandardWeight.toString();
                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel.verticalCenter = 1;

                            criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalBackground.addElement(criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalLabel);
                            totalGroup.addElement(criterionCurrentStandardWeightingTotalBackground);
                        }
                        this.chart.addElement(criteriaGroup);
                        this.chart.addElement(totalGroup);
                    }
                }
            }
```

It ends up looking like this after iterating through all the data. Approx 150 - 200 rows.
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U42Iq.jpg)

I took out some of the code just so its more readable and you didn't have to scroll far but you get the gist of what I am doing here. Is there a better way to do this? Is it even possible to get this to perform faster since I am creating a ton of components per iteration? Any tips appreciated, in terms of UI I couldn't be happier but performance is ridiculous.

Comment: I think you should ask the question what it is that Spark DataGrid can't do that you want it to do. Judging from the image you added, I can see nothing that can't be done with a DataGrid. Is it really worth weeks of development time to recreate similar functionality, probably with poorer performance? (On a side note: there is no Spark AdvancedDataGrid as you seem to suggest).

Comment: the light blue headers appear for every group and has a custom total row at the bottom of each as well. if this can be done with a datagrid please let me know. I'd be happy to try that route again

Comment: If you need "Excel in Flex" I suggest checking this out: https://github.com/mraak/AS-Spreadsheet (source) and this sample  http://currentlabel.co.uk/flexuscalculus/ . I had some cursory input into the API behind this during initial development phases and think it is a pretty impressive feat of engineering.

Comment: If the column widths are fixed, you could even do it with a List, which would be even better for performance. If you need resizeable columns though, it'll involve some more trickery (I've written an answer somewhere to address a similar situation, but can't seem to find it right now).

Comment: the columns are fixed, interested to see how you would go about putting all the columns/rows in a list

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the two following tricks:

1. Put the things that can be combined into a single separate component (for example each row as a component). I have experienced that this will usually speed up things a bit.
2. Create the illusion of fast rendering by creating the first 10-20 rows (to fill the visible screen), and then create one row each 5-10 ms (numbers are just to give an idea, and they depend on your situation). This way the your webpage will stay responsive and appear fast.

Hope it helps!

Comment: the screen stays locked until its done iterating through all the data. do you know of a way around this?

Comment: Considering a delay between adding each row, will prevent that freeze. How do you iterate and delay?

Comment: I am not familiar with 'delay' between adding each row(fairly new at flex). The code simply executes the for loops as scene in the code above and when its done the page appears. It would be great if they could still interact with the page while each row is being drawn

Comment: What I mean is that you add the first 20 rows, then for example use `setTimeout(addMoreRows, 25)` and in `setMoreRows` function, add another  row, and if the rows are not finished then call `setTimeout(addMoreRows, 25)` again at the end of that function (until the rows are completely generated). This way, the Flash player will have some time to refresh and respond to user inputs in between adding new rows.

Comment: great i'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is a performance test to figure out how long some small number of iterations takes (get time in ms before and after calls).  Figure out how many you can shove into 1/24th of a second.  That's how much time you have between frames in Flex.  Execute your data grid data provider update for said number of rows, then callLater() on the next batch.  callLater literally means "on the next frame"

Do this with caution.  CallLater is not a consistent time in the future because of all the other things that need to happen between Flash frames.